# Remote SSH access via HTML

Tags: linux, ssh, apache-httpd, html

Actually on my network infrastructure, we have many Layer 2 & layer 3 devices and network admins work a lot on that.

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and i installed apache2 on it.

I wanted to know how I can ssh on my devices using any browser.

For e.g, I browse to my server IP from a computer on the network, on the html page there will be a list of devices, I'll select one and SSH directly on it.

Do you have any idea.

Comment: Is this a software-rec question? Did you consider any software available? Keyword to search the web "web-based ssh". e.g. serfish or webssh.

Comment: In fact the list of devices which I want to SSH, don't have internet access, it is used only for management internally.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is https://github.com/shellinabox/shellinabox

Other alternatives: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web-based_SSH

Comment: Would you mind giving a little more description of what these are and how they fit what the user is asking for, rather than a [link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).